# doing an Or in a Left Join times out

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have a table that calculates a sum of numbers per person. This table is then looked into to get that number to add it to another set of data. The left join doing this works if I only have it linking to the column but there are 2 possible columns it needs to link to, and when I add the `or` part to link to the second column it times out.

The lookup table ENT.Sessions:

```
Select
    pupilonrolltableid,
    pupilnolongeronrolltableid,
    sum(sessions) As Sessions
From CensusAttendance
Where attendancereason NOT LIKE '%[/\BDJLPSVWXY#]%'
Group By pupilnolongeronrolltableid, pupilonrolltableid
```

I'm using both columns; since both won't be populated it will be one or the other, i.e

[image]

This is the SQL to build the data for the new table and where I'm using left joins to get the data out of Sessions table.

Census Table:

```
Select
     Coalesce(ONR.forename,OFR.forename) As Forename
    ,Coalesce(ONR.middlenames,OFR.middlenames) As Middlenames
    ,Coalesce(ONR.surname,OFR.surname) As Surname
    ,Coalesce(ONR.upn,OFR.upn) As UPN
    ,Coalesce(ONR.[schoolcensustableid],OFR.[schoolcensustableid]) As SchoolCensusTableID
    ,CSC.term As Term
    ,CSC.[year] As [Year]
    ,Case When TSO.Sessions IS NULL Then Cast('0.00' As Decimal(10,2)) Else TSO.Sessions END As SessionsAuthorised
    ,Case When ONR.termlysessionspossible IS NULL Then Cast('0.00' As Decimal(10,2)) Else ONR.termlysessionspossible END As SessionsPossibleOnRoll
    ,Case When OFR.termlysessionspossible IS NULL Then Cast('0.00' As Decimal(10,2)) Else OFR.termlysessionspossible END As SessionsPossibleOffRoll
    ,ONR.termlysessionseducational As TermlySessionsEducationalOnRoll
    ,OFR.termlysessionseducational As TermlySessionsEducationalOffRoll
    ,ONR.termlysessionsexceptional As TermlySessionsExceptionalOnRoll
    ,OFR.termlysessionsexceptional As TermlySessionsExceptionalOffRoll
    ,ONR.termlysessionsauthorised As TermlySessionsAuthorisedOnRoll
    ,OFR.termlysessionsauthorised As TermlySessionsAuthorisedOffRoll
    ,ONR.termlysessionsunauthorised As TermlySessionsUnauthorisedOnRoll
    ,OFR.termlysessionsunauthorised As TermlySessionsUnauthorisedOffRoll
    ,Coalesce (ONR.DateTimeInserted, OFR.DateTimeInserted) As DateTimeInserted
    ,Coalesce (ONR.DateTimeUpdated,OFR.DateTimeUpdated) As DateTimeUpdated
    ,Coalesce (ONR.MD5Checksum, OFR.MD5Checksum) As MD5Checksum
    ,Coalesce (ONR.LoadID, OFR.LoadID) As LoadID
    ,Coalesce (ONR.UniversalID, OFR.UniversalID) As UniversalID
From STG.Census_PupilOnRoll As ONR
Full Outer Join STG.Census_PupilNoLongerOnRoll As OFR
On ONR.schoolcensustableid = OFR.schoolcensustableid
And ONR.upn = OFR.upn
Left Outer Join STG.Census_SchoolCensus As CSC
On ONR.schoolcensustableid = CSC.schoolcensustableid
Or OFR.schoolcensustableid = CSC.schoolcensustableid
Left Outer Join ENT.CensusSessions As TSO
On TSO.pupilnolongeronrolltableid = OFR.pupilnolongeronrolltableid
Or TSO.pupilonrolltableid = ONR.pupilonrolltableid
```

If I leave the last left outer join at the first `On` `=` it will load data but only linking to some of the data from Sessions, but once I add the `Or` it never loads.

How do I get it working?

There are over a million records in Sessions and the SQL building the other data set has 2-3 million.

Comment: If you check the execution plan you'll see the server can't use any index seek operations on those `OR` conditions so it has to scan the entire table or index. That `OR` condition means the server has to seek to find matches for the first condition, store the results somewhere (actually in tempdb) and *then* seek again to find matches for the second condition.

Comment: Are you certain that you need a full join rather than just a union?

Comment: @shawnt00 a union just puts the data in one list if im not mistaken so my data would just be after eachother, but i need it so it links together as data from both tables link together to make 1 full record

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have better luck if you structure it to do all the joins separately:

```
with Census_PupilOnRoll As (
    Select ONR.*, CSC.term, CSC."year", TSO.sessions
    From STG.Census_PupilOnRoll As ONR
        Left Outer Join STG.Census_SchoolCensus As CSC 
            On CSC.schoolcensustableid = ONR.schoolcensustableid
        Left Outer Join ENT.CensusSessions As TSO
            On TSO.pupilonrolltableid = ONR.pupilonrolltableid
), Census_PupilNoLongerOnRoll as (
    Select OFR.*, CSC.term, CSC."year", TSO.sessions
    From STG.Census_PupilNoLongerOnRoll As OFR
        Left Outer Join STG.Census_SchoolCensus As CSC
            On CSC.schoolcensustableid = OFR.schoolcensustableid
        Left Outer Join ENT.CensusSessions As TSO 
            On TSO.pupilnolongeronrolltableid = OFR.pupilnolongeronrolltableid
)
Select * /* <-- your output columns go here */
From Census_PupilOnRoll As ONR
    Full Outer Join Census_PupilNoLongerOnRoll As OFR
        On ONR.schoolcensustableid = OFR.schoolcensustableid And ONR.upn = OFR.upn;
```